# Configuring hystrix command properties using application.yaml in Spring-Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am having same issue, where i am trying to override the hystrix properties in application.yaml. When I run the app & check the properties with localhost:port/app-context/hystrix.stream, I get all default values instead.

here is the hystrix config in my application.yaml

```
hystrix:
   command.StoreSubmission.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
   command.StoreSubmission.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold: 4
   command.StoreSubmission.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 60000
   command.StoreSubmission.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds: 180000
   collapser.StoreSubmission.maxRequestsInBatch: 1
   collapser.StoreSubmission.requestCache.enabled: FALSE
   threadpool.StoreSubmission.coreSize: 30
   threadpool.StoreSubmission.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds: 180000
```

Here is what I see when I hit the url - localhost:port/app-context/hystrix.stream in browser [ this is same stream url used for hystrix dashboard ] -

```
data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"storeSubmission","group":"StoreSubmission","currentTime":1435941064801,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":0,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"latencyExecute_mean":0,"latencyExecute":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"latencyTotal_mean":0,"latencyTotal":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"THREAD","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1}

data: {"type":"HystrixThreadPool","name":"StoreSubmission","currentTime":1435941064801,"currentActiveCount":0,"currentCompletedTaskCount":35,"currentCorePoolSize":30,"currentLargestPoolSize":30,"currentMaximumPoolSize":30,"currentPoolSize":30,"currentQueueSize":0,"currentTaskCount":35,"rollingCountThreadsExecuted":0,"rollingMaxActiveThreads":0,"propertyValue_queueSizeRejectionThreshold":5,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":180000,"reportingHosts":1}
```

The problem is with hystrix command & collapser properties, where as threadpool properties are set correctly. I have got following annotations in my **@configuration** class -

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableHystrix
@EnableHystrixDashboard
```

Has someone tried configuring hystrix command properties using application.yaml in thier Spring-Boot application, can help please?

Comment: I'm looking at this and notice the name coming from the HystrixCommand data is lower case and your configuration is uppercase.

Comment: I pasted your values in my `application.yml` and those values came through.

Comment: @spencergibb: 1. The name coming through in HystrixCommand data is method name which was wrapped by HystrixCommand. 2.In the configuration its groupKey value, actaully this should be commandKey value. 3. When you say these values come up, where?

Comment: I am also working on this now & I think I am getting closer to the solution. will post the solution once I have tested it & know it works.

Comment: Those values came through the hystrix.stream.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The main problem was that, I was using groupKey value instead of commandKey value to define the properties. The wiki page for these configuration properties - https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#intro says -

```
hystrix.command.HystrixCommandKey.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds
```

Replace the HystrixCommandKey portion of the property with the value you set for commandkey.

```
hystrix.threadpool.HystrixThreadPoolKey.coreSize
```

Replace the HystrixThreadPoolKey portion of the property with the value you set for threadPoolKey.

Here is how I define both commandKey & threadPoolKey over the method wrapped by HystrixCommand -

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "StoreSubmission", commandKey = "StoreSubmission", threadPoolKey = "StoreSubmission")
public String storeSubmission(ReturnType returnType, InputStream is, String id) {
}
```

You can actually define both command & threadpool properties on the method within **@HystixCommand** annotation.

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "StoreSubmission", commandKey = "StoreSubmission", threadPoolKey = "StoreSubmission", commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "4"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "60000"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "180000") }, threadPoolProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "30"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "180000") })
public String storeSubmission(ReturnType returnType, InputStream is, String id) {
}
```

I guess the best way to define these properties is in externalized application.yaml, that way you can control it better & change them for different environments.

Comment: Do you know how can I verify that these properties are being applied to configure HystrixCommand? Is there anyway of logging them? Is it possible to enable DEBUG level logging for Hystrix?

Comment: @pijushcse 
logging:
  level:
  com.netflix.hystrix: 'DEBUG'. 
First time you enter in the fallback you can see all the values

Comment: From spring-cloud-netflix docs: "The HystrixCommand is provided by a Netflix contrib library called "javanica". Spring Cloud automatically wraps Spring beans with that annotation in a proxy that is connected to the Hystrix circuit breaker. The circuit breaker calculates when to open and close the circuit, and what to do in case of a failure. To configure the HystrixCommand you can use the commandProperties attribute with a list of HystrixProperty annotations." Details: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#configuration

Comment: What is the purpose of the `groupKey`? Metrics?

Comment: @wilmol: GroupKey is used to group together multiple HystrixCommand objects such as for reporting, alerting, dashboard.

Comment: What happens when circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold(12) is greater than HystrixThreadPool core size(10). In this case if all the Threads (10) in the ThreadPool got failed, Does Circuit Breaker never opens, because it didn't reach requestVolumeThreshold(12) or how it will execute this scenario?