# How to configure Hystrix annotations from property file?

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

I use the Hystrix-Javanica library to apply the circuit breaker via annotations. I'd like to configure Hystrix with properties defined in the Spring configuration. Since my application uses Spring AOP, I hoped something like this would work:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {
  @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "${cb.requestVolumeThreshold}")
})
public boolean checkWebservice(String id) { ... }
```

But this fails with `bad property value. property name 'circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold'. Expected int value`

Any ideas how I can configure Hystrix without hard coding the values?

Comment: you can also follow this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211685/configuring-hystrix-command-properties-using-application-yaml-in-spring-boot-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using property placeholders inside the Hystrix annotations didn't work out.

Instead I chose to define the full configuration properties, e.g.:

```
hystrix.command.checkWebservice.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=10
```

And I added this Spring Configuration class to load spring properties into [Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius):

```
@Configuration
public class HystrixConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean props;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ConfigurationManager.install(props.getConfiguration());
    }
}
```

---

[Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/) may be an alternative for this setup, but it requires Spring Boot.

Comment: For me the ConfigurationManager.install(props.getConfiguration()); replaced some important properties. In my case I had to do  ConfigurationManager.loadPropertiesFromConfiguration(props.getConfiguration()); and everything worked. Thank you!