# How to load application properties dynamically in @HystrixProperty annotation

Tags: spring, properties, hystrix

Working method with hardcoded values for @HystricProperty:

```
@HystrixCommand(ignoreExceptions={HttpClientErrorException.class},
        //groupKey="ProductServiceGroup",commandKey = "test", threadPoolKey = "ProductInfoDetailsThreadPool",
        commandProperties = {
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS, value="500"),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, value="1500"),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.CIRCUIT_BREAKER_ENABLED, value="true"),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.CIRCUIT_BREAKER_REQUEST_VOLUME_THRESHOLD, value="20"),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_INTERRUPT_ON_TIMEOUT, value="true"),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.EXECUTION_ISOLATION_SEMAPHORE_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, value="20")
        },
        fallbackMethod = "reliable")
public Map readingList() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(950);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended");
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Map.class);
}
```

I don't want to hardcode these values in @HystrixProperty annotation, instead want to read these properties from application.properties.

some thing like this:
@HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, value="${timeout.in.millis}")

Comment: create a property in application.properties like this `hystrix.command.test.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=3000` where test is the commandkey

Comment: you can follow this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211685/configuring-hystrix-command-properties-using-application-yaml-in-spring-boot-app

Answer (score 0):

you could use a properties placeholder.
Define it in your spring configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myapp.properties" />
```

then create the properties file myapp.propertiesand put in in your classpath, as referenced in the configuration. the content could be

```
CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE=500
EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE=1500
```

and so on...

then you can use that parameters in  your @HistrixCommand just as you wrote

```
HystrixCommand(ignoreExceptions={HttpClientErrorException.class},
        //groupKey="ProductServiceGroup",commandKey = "test", threadPoolKey = "ProductInfoDetailsThreadPool",
        commandProperties = {
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS, value=${CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE}),
                @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, value=${EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE}),
 ...
```

Comment: I have added these properties to application.properties and it is set in classpath.  I can use these properties using "${timeout.in.millis}" in @Value() annotation and other places but not in @HystrixProperty annotation. Any thing that you can help here?

Comment: if you try @HystrixProperty(name=HystrixPropertiesManager.CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS, value=${CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE}), you have an error ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting error that invalid value is being passed. expected value is Integer. wait i will give you the exact error

Comment: I would try with value=#{new Integer('${CIRCUIT_BREAKER_SLEEP_WINDOW_IN_MILLISECONDS_VALUE}')}

Comment: When I try with what you suggested, I am getting this error.                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad property value. property name 'execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds'. Expected int value, actual = #{new Integer('${hystrix.timeout.millis}')}

Comment: maybe this post is good for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143918/setting-class-level-annotation-values-from-application-yml?rq=1